# useNavigate from root directory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to redirect a user after they click on a text with `useNavigate`, the route that i'm trying to use is "behind" the current route whereas `useNavigate` redirects "forward".

code:

```
<span onClick={() => navigate(`portfolio/${user}`)}
      className="text-orange-400 cursor-pointer"
              >
                {profile?.name}
              </span>
```

current route is `http://localhost:3000/packages/PUeV5ZTXMfTRFIsoYyKi` and the route is redirected to is `http://localhost:3000/packages/PUeV5ZTXMfTRFIsoYyKi/portfolio/ZLPxfKnsf9sYo3l9QljPD9dfq8qM` instead of `http://localhost:3000/portfolio/PUeV5ZTXMfTRFIsoYyKi`.

I've also tried `` onClick={() => navigate(`portfolio/${user}`, { replace: true })} `` but the redirect is the same.

Answer (score 1):

because this is a relative route.
To navigate to an absolute route you need to start with `/`

```
navigate(`/portfolio/${user}`
```

Answer (score 1):

<span onClick={() => navigate(`/portfolio/${user}`)}
...